# Talkback speed is very fast, how can I reduce it in Samsung S21

Tags: samsung, accessibility, android-11, talk-back

I have Samsung S21 5G Android 11 mobile. This device Talkback talking speed is very fast that I am not able to catch it.

How can I reduce speed ?

Comment: On Pixel 3a, there is a Setting inside TalkBack menu about Text-to-speech, and there's a Speech rate slider inside it. Not sure what Settings are available on Samsung.

Comment: @AndrewT. Its working in Samsung too.